# “http://localhost:1935” works but not “http://192.168.1.3:1935” in WAMP

Tags: windows-7, wamp

Running a Wowza streaming engine and WAMP server.

`http://localhost:1935` works but not `http://192.168.1.3:1935`

Using Windows 7 as my server.

I Added a line towards end of this section

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/"> 
Require ip 192.168.1
</Directory
```

[image]

Included 192.168.1.3:1935 in Listen directive as well.
Did port forwarding as well as shown in image.

What do I need to do to get `http://192.168.1.3:1935`working? This will help me run Wowza streaming engine.

Comment: Name based virtual host?

Comment: You shouldn't need to forward any ports unless you want the server accessible via the external broadband IP. If you can't access using your NAT assigned IP address then you have incorrect settings in WAMP.

Comment: Could you please show your `httpd.conf` file for your WAMP server.

Comment: What computers are you testing from and how are they connected to the server? Is the router the only box separating the server computer from the client? or is the client physically located elsewhere in the world that connects to the internet in order to access your router and then server?

Comment: Try to disable your firewall

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with your IP settings of your server. please look at which IP your server is using:

1. Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button Picture of the
   Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box,
   type adapter, and then, under Network and Sharing Center, click View
   network connections.
2. Select an active network connection, and then, in the toolbar, click
   View status of this connection. (You might need to click the chevron
   Picture of the chevron icon to find this command.)
3. Click Details.

This is the IP your installation will be accessible on. You should not need the virtualhost setting you mentioned.